# Adavantage of using connection from Data Source over JDBC Driver Manager

Tags: java, tomcat, jdbc, datasource

Question is basically identify the best practices on data access layer.

I want to choose in between using a data source  or traditional driver manager to load the the connection on web applications.  I know very clearly following advantages

1. Flexibility of configuration
2. In built connection pooling mechanism

But if I can sacrifice advantage of flexibility with configuration and have own connection pooling mechanism, Do I get any other benefit out of data source. In other way around what are limitations or issues I would face while having application managed jdbc driver connection than container managed.

I know the question is so stupid that I should be knowing the advantage of somebody takes care of handling connection than my application.  But this is rare scenario where I can't use datasource in web application.  I would be looking following things

1. How better I can design own connection pool my self?
2. Is there any thing else I should take care when I access connection through DriverManager API

Comment: Out of curiosity, why can't you use a datasource?

Comment: 1. Application will have an option to configure one or more data bases, and can be added run time ; 2. Customer may not be liking manual changes in context.xml every time we have to add /change databases

Comment: Instead of implementing your own connection management, why don't you instantiate a datasource programmatically? There are plenty of implementations available already

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Note that is is very possible to programmatically create a `DataSource` (backed by a connection pool) dynamically based on user input.

Using Apache Commons-dbcp:

```
BasicDataSource ds = new BasicDataSource();
ds.setDriverClassName(DATABASE_DRIVER_CLASS);
ds.setUsername(DATABASE_USERNAME);
ds.setPassword(DATABASE_PASSWORD);
ds.setUrl(DATABASE_URL);
ds.setInitialSize(1);
ds.setMaxActive(50);
ds.setDefaultAutoCommit(false);
```

So I think the question is not really between a `DataSource` and no-`DataSource`, but rather between a container managed `DataSource` and an application managed `DataSource`.

Container managed `DataSources` are easier to manage by server-admin types.  They can be tuned through the app server web UI, etcApplication managed `DataSources` do not have this advantage.

Comment: Looks like a cool solution,does this behave same what container maintained data sources ( Memory management, pooling etc)?

Comment: Yes.  In fact, Tomcat happens to use commons-dbcp for their internal data source implementation.